# PostgreSQL find records and sort by left outer join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-postgresql

I'm trying to order retrieved records by a field on a left outer join in the following SQL query:

```
@companies = Company.scoped
@companies = @companies.where("companies.is_deleted = 'f' AND companies.state IN (?)", ["draft", "pending"])
@companies = @companies.includes(:events)
@companies = @companies.order("events.created_at DESC")
```

---

```
SELECT "companies"."id" AS t0_r0, "companies"."name" AS t0_r1, "companies"."reference" AS t0_r2, "companies"."state" AS t0_r3, "companies"."description" AS t0_r4, "companies"."remarks" AS t0_r5 "events"."id" AS t2_r0, "events"."eventable_type" AS t2_r1, "events"."eventable_id" AS t2_r2, "events"."event_type" AS t2_r3, "events"."creator_company_id" AS t2_r4, "events"."creator_user_id" AS t2_r5, "events"."created_at" AS t2_r6
FROM "companies"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "events" ON "events"."eventable_id" = "companies"."id" AND "events"."eventable_type" = 'company'
WHERE "companies"."is_deleted" = 'f' AND companies.state IN ('draft','pending')
ORDER BY events.created_at DESC
```

But the retrieved records are not sorted properly as expected (i.e. by events.created_at)

Any clue how to successfully do that while keeping performance efficient?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "*not sorted properly*"? What would a "proper" sort order be?

Comment: records are not sorted by 'events.created_at DESC' as instructed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `ORDER BY` works correctly in Postgres. Please show us an example output of what you think is not correct. Are you aware that `events.created_at` might contain NULL values due to the outer join?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, I am aware.
Any idea how to ignore created_at NULL values in the LEFT OUTER JOIN query?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I checked events.created_at column for NULL values and found none.

Comment: Please show us **an example** of the "wrong" sort order. Without that, nobody will be able to answer your question. Oh: and what's the datatype of `created_at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should not be using LEFT JOIN, or if the code generates LEFT JOIN in this case, it is probably wrong.

> The result of a left outer join (or simply left join) for table A and B always contains all records of the "left" table (A)," -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join

Thus, if you do not wish to have all records from COMPANIES, **even when there is no match on events**, you should not really be using left join here. It will result rows with NULL values for the right side table.